# How to write a Java application that mimics sbt's changing text output in console screen (while resolving dependencies)?

Tags: java, console, sbt

Upon starting `sbt` the following line stays on the same line with `[info] Resolving` part fixed while `org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...` part keeps changing displaying libraries being resolved.

```
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
```

My questions are:

1. What is this called?
2. How to write a Java program to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

This is done in `sbt` using escape sequences to erase the previous output before writing the updated value.  Take a look at the implementation of the [ConsoleOut](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13.5/util/log/src/main/scala/sbt/ConsoleOut.scala) trait for details.

Here is a sample of this technique.  The [JANSI](http://jansi.fusesource.org/) library is required on Windows:

```
import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AnsiConsole.systemInstall();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print("Hello, world " + i + "% complete\n");
            Thread.sleep(200);
            System.out.print("\u001B[1A\u001B[2K");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know a Mac/Linux way as well?

Comment: i ran it, and the output is still "Hello, world 0% complete
Hello, world 1% complete
Hello, world 2% complete
Hello, world 3% complete"

Comment: I found out the reason! it is strange that if I execute the program in eclipse, it is still showing as line-by-line, but if I execute it on the command-line directly, it is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the difficulties are.  There is no specific name for it as far as I know.  As for achieving it - very simple indeed. You have one text string template: `Resolving %1$s...` - you then use `String.format` using different parameters - and set the result into a text field.

Comment: What I perceived as difficult is that the text is changed in place. It is not printed out on screen line-by-line, in the usual way. :)